# Issue with sending email through ses

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, boto3, amazon-ses, dkim

My function is supposed to take an email adress and send a prewritten email to said email address. The only problem is that I keep getting the email sent back to sender and marked as spam. Not sure what the issue is. Is the email getting sent back it’s spam or is it marked spam because the email failed to deliver? The message is as follows:
[image: screenshot]

I am sending through my email as a verified identity and verified it through email but not through dkim. Our domain also has not finished dkim configuration either when I checked, is this the issue?

Here is my code, is there a problem with it ? I tried to write code to be able to catch the error but to no avail. Any suggestion is very appreciated.

```
def email_reminder(user, subject_line, days_since_login, ses_client):

        if days_since_login >= 60:
            beginning_email_lines = f"""
                                    Hello {user},
            
                                    We've noticed that you have not logged into your AWS account in {days_since_login} days. 
            
                                          Your account has been been locked out."""
            
        else:
            beginning_email_lines = f"""
                                    Hello {user},
            
                                    We've noticed that you have not logged into your AWS account in {days_since_login} days. 
            
                                              your account will be locked out in {60 - days_since_login} day(s)."""

        counter = 0
        # call ses email function to send email to users based days since their last login
        while counter < 2:
            try:
                ses_client.send_email(
                    Source=
    'admin@ourdomain.com',
                    Destination={
                        'ToAddresses': [user]
                    },
                    Message={
                        'Subject': {
                            'Data': subject_line
                        },
                        'Body': {
                            'Text': {
                                'Data': f""" {beginning_email_lines}

  
                                """
                            }
                        }
                    }
                )
            except Exception as e:
                counter += 1
                if counter >= 2:
                    logger.error(f"could not send email to user {user}, retries exceeded")
                    raise Exception("could not send email to user")
                else:
                    logger.error(f"could not send mail to {user}, error : {e}, trying again")
                    pass
```

Comment: I think it is flagged as spam because the From: address does not match the actual sender.

Comment: This is probably due to that SES uses as shared email server with alot of different AWS accoutns/SES Senders. And due to this the the DMARC value is probably not that good. I think gmail has a pretty allowing DMARC policy in place. You can test and send a Email a gmail address to see if it goes throgh.

Comment: @JohnGordon wdym the from : address doesn’t match the actual sender? If you mean I need to use my own email I have in ses then I already am. However our domain nor is my email is dkim verified.

Comment: @ErikAsplund I sent from using an email with our domain to a recipient who had a google email. I’m not quite sure what you mean though.